# Multiple backslashes in string java regex

Tags: java, regex

So I have a string `X1X2X3\\\\`. I only want to capture the AlphaNumerics values. My regex is `([A-z0-9]*).*`. But it will return `X1X2X3\\`. My code looks like this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([A-z0-9]*).*");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
matcher.matches();
return matcher.group(1);
```

Would like to find regex Answer. Not String.replaceAll() or replace() :)

Comment: Do you have a  *string* ``X1X2X3\\\\``, or a *string literal* `"X1X2X3\\\\"`? Also, your regex is wrong as it `[A-z]` can match non-alphanumeric characters.

Comment: String literal `assertThat(trimSpecialCharacters("X1X2X3\\\\"), is("X1X2X3"));`

Comment: ok `"([A-Za-z0-9]*).*"` fixed it thanks!

Comment: I think the problem is in `A-z`, you want `A-Za-z` instead. `A-z` matches chars between `Z` and `a` which aren't letters.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with `A-z` in `[A-z0-9]`, which can match non-alpha characters as well, namely the code points between `Z` and `a`.

The correct expression to use is `[A-Za-z0-9]` for alphanumeric characters, or the predefined character class `\\w`.

(credit goes to all those who pointed out the mistake in comments)